# Apache redirect drops first '/' of path

Tags: apache-2.4

My Apache configuration for `foo.com` is like this

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    ServerName foo.com
    ServerAlias foo.com

    ...    

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost _default_:80>
    ServerName foo.com
    ServerAlias foo.com
    Redirect permanent / https://foo.com
</VirtualHost>
```

If I navigate to `foo.com/bar` in the browser I get redirected to `https://foo.combar`, which is missing the forward slash between the domain and the path.

If I type `https://foo.com/bar` into the browser directly the site works correctly.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the `Redirect` line should be like:

```
Redirect permanent "/" "https://foo.com/"
```

Pay attention to the last / after foo.com.

Comment: Can you explain what is different and why it matters?

Comment: Because the official documentation here:

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect

uses double quotes.

Comment: @chicks You are right. Using or not double quotes makes no different at all. The specific problem can be solved by just adding a / at the end of https://foo.com